# Tailwind css with craco installed, it doesnt work

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am creating a React web application. I have installed Tailwind along with craco using instructions on the official Tailwind documentation [Tailwind v2 Docs (Create React App)](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app). But when I use class names in App.js such as bg-grey-100, results dont appear. Help

App.js:

```js
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  return <div classname="bg-grey-100">app</div>;
};

export default App;
```

global.css:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

package.json:

```
{
   "name":"discoverio",
   "version":"0.1.0",
   "private":true,
   "dependencies":{
      "@craco/craco":"^7.1.0",
      "@testing-library/jest-dom":"^5.17.0",
      "@testing-library/react":"^13.4.0",
      "@testing-library/user-event":"^13.5.0",
      "react":"^18.2.0",
      "react-dom":"^18.2.0",
      "react-scripts":"5.0.1",
      "web-vitals":"^2.1.4"
   },
   "scripts":{
      "start":"craco start",
      "build":"craco build",
      "test":"craco test",
      "eject":"react-scripts eject"
   },
   "eslintConfig":{
      "extends":[
         "react-app",
         "react-app/jest"
      ]
   },
   "browserslist":{
      "production":[
         ">0.2%",
         "not dead",
         "not op_mini all"
      ],
      "development":[
         "last 1 chrome version",
         "last 1 firefox version",
         "last 1 safari version"
      ]
   },
   "devDependencies":{
      "autoprefixer":"^9.8.8",
      "postcss":"^7.0.39",
      "tailwindcss":"npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.17"
   }
}
```

tailwind config:

```js
module.exports = {
  purge: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./public/index.html"],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

craco config:

```js
// craco.config.js
module.exports = {
  style: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [require("tailwindcss"), require("autoprefixer")],
    },
  },
};
```

index.js:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import "./global.css";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using (Create React App) it does not support custom PostCSS configurations and is incompatible with many important tools in the PostCSS ecosystem you are advised to us **Vite** as stated in the docs [Tailwind v3 Docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite)!

As for tailwind class names and colors review install tailwind extension [Tailwind CSS IntelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss)! from **Tailwind Labs** will help you greatly